# Isotope Multisort Sorting Incorrectly

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I am attempting to make an isotope sort with multisort, it will first sort by picked, then by the score. Currently picked has a value of 1 for everything. When I sort only by score only it sorts by score correctly, but when I sort by score and picked, the order seems incorrect.

Since all of the values for picked are 1, I would expect it to sort by score.

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xk7dtkeq/2/
Works correctly on the fiddle.

Initialize grid:

```
function initGrid(grid) {
    jQuery(grid).isotope({
  // options
  itemSelector: '.iso-item',
  layoutMode: 'masonry',
    getSortData: {
        score: function( itemElem ) {
              var score = jQuery( itemElem ).find('.score').text();
              return parseInt( score );
                },
        picked: function( itemElem ) {
              var picked = jQuery( itemElem ).find('.picked').text();
              return parseInt( picked );
                },
        }
});
}
```

Sort Grid

```
function sortGrid(grid) {
    jQuery(grid).isotope({
    sortBy : [ 'picked', 'score' ],
    sortAscending: false
    }); 
}
```

Comment: As far as I see, there is no `data-picked` defined, but a jsfiddle/jsbin to reproduce the issue, would help a lot....

Comment: Updated fiddle, works as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/xk7dtkeq/2/ so I am not sure what the issue is?

Comment: try to debug it by `console.log(score)` and `console.log(picked)` in the corresponding functions to see, whether the values are retrieved correctly.